# OpenSSL 1.1.0: Get stack from STACK_OF()

Tags: openssl

Since openssl 1.1.0 has made all the data structures opaque I'm refactoring my code and came across this:

```
STACK_OF(CMS_SignerInfo)* pSignatures = CMS_get0_SignerInfos(pCMS);
if (1 != M_sk_num(&pSignatures->stack)) 
{
//error
}
```

Since the member `stack` of type `node**` can't be accessed, it won't compile.
What getter function do I use to access the `stack`?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> `M_sk_num(&pSignatures->stack)`

This code seems to be returning the number of elements in the stack.

It can be replaced by a call to `sk_CMS_SignerInfo_num(pSignatures)`

See the man page here:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/sk_TYPE_num.html